# display popover on uitextfield

Tags: ios, ipad, ios5, ios6, uipopovercontroller

I have created popover using the code below :

```
UIViewController* popoverContent = [[UIViewController alloc] init]; //ViewController

UIView *popoverView = [[UIView alloc] init];   //view
popoverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

UIDatePicker *datePicker=[[UIDatePicker alloc]init];//Date picker
datePicker.frame=CGRectMake(0,44,320, 216);
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime;
[datePicker setMinuteInterval:5];
[datePicker setTag:10];
[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(Result) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[popoverView addSubview:datePicker];

popoverContent.view = popoverView;
popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];
popoverController.delegate=self;
[popoverContent release];

[popoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 264) animated:NO];
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:tempButton.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];//tempButton.frame where you need you can put that frame
```

The tempbutton is a button created on uitextfied which is hidden (Created to get the frame in tempButton.frame ).

I was wondering if I can use any function in uitextfied which can be used instead of tempbutton.frame like uitextfied.frame or something.

Please let me know I am a noob in ios .

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
yourTextField.frame
```

Just like you would

```
tempButton.frame
```

Comment: I Bet that I had tried the same thing the other day but it did not work .Now its working !! WEIRD. I dont know how.Thanks Ryan it helped me a great deal.

Comment: No problem-- an outlet or something may have not been set which is maybe why it was not working when you tried before.

Comment: Quick add-on question: How to add SET DATE and Cancel button on the datepicker ?

Comment: Add a UIToolbar to the top with and create 2 UIBarButtonItems for each Set and Cancel, set them to the toolbar's rightBarButtonItem & leftBarButtonItem. If you need more help I can explain a little more

Comment: In the above example what would the CGRectMake for uitoolbar ? is it CGRectMake(0,44,0,0)  ?

Comment: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44) I believe would work fine. Than add it as a subView to your popoverView

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22424/discussion-between-jacob-wood-and-ryang)